# AtomicReference to array and array element changes visibility

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, atomic

Does Java guarantee that updates to array elements done by **thread A** before storing the array reference in an `AtomicReference` will be always visible to **thread B** that obtains this reference?

In other words, what are the possible outputs of executing this:

```
class References {
    AtomicReference<String[]> refs = new AtomicReference<>(new String[]{"first"});

    public void add(String s) {
        refs.updateAndGet(oldRefs -> {
            String[] newRefs = new String[oldRefs.length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(oldRefs, 0, newRefs, 0, oldRefs.length);
            newRefs[oldRefs.length] = s;
            return newRefs;
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        References r = new References();
        new Thread(() -> r.add("second")).start();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(r.refs.get()));
    }
}
```

can the above only print either `[first]` or `[first, second]`, or is it also possible to get results like `[first, null]` or `[null, null]`?

The javadoc for `java.util.concurrent.atomic` states:

> `compareAndSet` and all other read-and-update operations such as `getAndIncrement` have the memory effects of both reading and writing volatile variables.

which seems to not make any guarantees for the non-volatile elements of the array, only the array reference itself.

Comment: You will always get `{ "first", "second" }`; `System.arrayCopy()` doesn't return before it has completed its task (it would be pretty unreliable otherwise!)

Comment: If you assigned the array to a `final` field, you'd have such a guarantee, with `AtomicReference` I don't think you do.

Comment: By the way, I would probably use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, which gives you all the guarantees you can expect from such a collection.

Comment: On second thought, it is guaranteed that you'll only ever see `[first]` or `[first,second]` and nothing else.

Comment: @fge what you're saying about `arraycopy` actually only guaratees the first element will be "first", what I'm actually concerned about is whether the `newRefs[oldRefs.length] = s` assignment happens before making the array reference visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A volatile write to a variable will guarantee that everything that happened before it will have been happened before a subsequent volatile read of **that same variable**.

The relevant rules from the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html) are:

> **17.4.4. Synchronization Order**
>
> - A write to a volatile variable v (§8.3.1.4) synchronizes-with all subsequent reads of v by any thread (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).
>
> **17.4.5. Happens-before Order**
>
> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.
>
> If we have two actions x and y, we write hb(x, y) to indicate that x happens-before y.
>
> - If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then hb(x, y).
> - If an action x synchronizes-with a following action y, then we also have hb(x, y).
> - If hb(x, y) and hb(y, z), then hb(x, z).

As `AtomicReference` guarantees that your array reference is only stored/loaded in a volatile manner (and once written, you don't modify an existing array), this is enough to guarantee visibility of the results of `System.arrayCopy()` (and the line following it) for anyone calling `refs.get()`.

**However the construct still isn't entirely watertight** because anyone obtaining the array reference through `refs.get()` can then go on and make changes to the elements without the protection of `AtomicReference`.

`CopyOnWriteArrayList` works very similar to this (it uses the combination of a `ReentrantLock` and a `volatile` array field instead of an `AtomicReference`), except it is also guaranteed that no-one can obtain the underlying array and play around with it in a non-safe manner.

Answer (score 1):

you can't get any null element in the array because you did not not modify the array elements in your code but you create a new one every time (`String[] newRefs = new String[oldRefs.length + 1];`). Since you are storing the array reference and you did not modify its elements you cannot see null elements.
If in your code you have something like:

```
   refs.updateAndGet(oldRefs -> {
        if (oldRefs.size>0) oldRefs[0]=null;//is an example just for "fun"
        String[] newRefs = new String[oldRefs.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(oldRefs, 0, newRefs, 0, oldRefs.length);
        newRefs[oldRefs.length] = s;
        return newRefs;
    });
```

then you can see something different, and some users may see null value in the first element

**UPDATE**:
since AtomicReference works only for the reference to the Array you can use [AtomicReferenceArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReferenceArray.html) to access in a safer way to the array elements

Comment: the null elements I was asking about do not come from erasing references in existing array, but from potential releasing of array reference before all the elements are set to proper values - after array creation they are null, and remain so until updated to other values later.

Comment: @pdabro when you get access to the array reference you can modifiy its elements without "the protection" of atomic reference; my example was trying to show this case, i.e. you are protecting the reference and not the elements.

Answer (score 1):

An `AtomicReference` to an array is no different than any other - it is only the **reference** that is atomic and therefore has the relevant memory barriers in place. Accessing the array is just like any other object - no extra protection.

You will therefore always get `[first]` or `[first, second]` and no other option as you are creating the new array, populating it and placing it back into the old reference which is atomically protected.

Java arrays are not very good at resizing. If you want a resizeable structure you would do better to use an `ArrayList`. If you want concurrent access to it use a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) which is essentially what you are trying to implement in your code.